# Adding space in an electronic BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, urls

I am using JabRef to create my references. I want to put a note for the for the access date (for electronic references)
Here is an example:

```
@ELECTRONIC{qwest,
  url = {http://gigaom.com/cleantech/smart-grid-dsl-current-and-qwest-team-up/  [Accessed: Nov, 2012]},
}
```

However, if I use the one above, it looks bad since there is no space between `up/`  and `[A`.

How can I make it look better?

Comment: The `biblatex` package supports a `urlseen` label, which you can use for specifying the date relevant for the URL. I haven't played with it.

Comment: Or, you can use the field `note` with contents `[Nov 2012]` or `[Accessed: Nov 2012].` But @MarcvanDongen 's solution is clearly better.

Comment: it works in a desired way!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

(Derived from the comments of Marc van Dongen and tohecz)

The `biblatex` package supports an `urlseen` label which you can use for specifying the date relevant for the URL. Without `biblatex`, you can use the field `note` with contents `[Nov 2012]` or `[Accessed: Nov 2012]`.